# iPod touch reports incorrect location

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, geolocation, ipod-touch

I have borrowed my friend's first gen iPod touch to test my app on. I upgraded the OS to iOS 3.1.3.

I have been following the big nerd ranch book and am trying to get the location to display in the log, but it's inside a view rather than the app delegate.

The location is reported but for some reason it gives her address, over 300 miles away....

The separate maps app reports that it cannot determine my location

I turned the geolocation services on and off and I can only find my home network listed so I can't make the device forget her network.

Here is the code i am using:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    [locationManager setDelegate:self];

    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];

    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; 
}




-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
   NSLog(@"%@", newLocation);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I am connected to my home network 300 miles from hers

also the log result is:

```
 <anumber,anumber>+/- 144.27m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2009-06-28 17:58:08 +0100
```

It seems to think it is 2009...

thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's using a cached location, and in the place you are now it can't get a location fix. Try testing it again in a place with lots of WiFi (a city/big suburb). Also, check to see if you can find a location in the maps app.

Comment: Thanks @nevan The maps app keeps saying "your location could not be determined"

Comment: Your app will be using the same hardware as the maps app. Probably the maps app has some code to detect old location data and ignore it. There's no easy way to test location code properly without an iPhone with a GPS chip (iPhone 3G up) or a Touch combined with being physically close to lots of WiFi. The Touch uses a database of WiFi IDs and GPS to make a guess to location.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is nothing wrong, the iPod touch does not have a GPS chip. It uses triangulation of WiFi ESSID to vindt it's location.

It will need a network connection to do this correctly.

Comment: It is connected to my home network.....is this not enough?  Also it obviously got the current lat and longitude somehow. I'm presuming it did that using the wifi triangulation using her home network. Why can it not repeat the procedure?

Comment: There is no triangulation. It asks Skyhook Wireless for the location of your wifi network. To see why Skyhook is off by 300 miles: http://www.skyhookwireless.com/howitworks/coverage.php

Comment: Apple [no longer uses Skyhook](http://www.fool.com/investing/general/2010/08/04/apple-drops-skyhook-wireless-technology-from-iphon.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There was this one time when the timezone on the WiFi router was set incorrectly and that kind of screwed up location info on iPods.

Check your router settings.

Comment: I've checked, the router reports the correct date, it gets it from the internet

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an iPhone?

- Make sure the GPS is on (run maps for a bit, small accuracy circle around the blue dot).
- Make sure it can see your WiFi network (join it).

Maybe try this with another iPhone also.

Sync the devices with iTunes, and hope that Apple's location/ESSID database is updated by those iPhones at some time in the near future :)